# How to convert ByteBuffer to BodyInit in Scala.js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I want to use the `sendBeacon` API in Scala.js and send binary data in form of a `ByteBuffer` but I am failing to convert it to `BodyInit`. I am using [boopickle](https://boopickle.suzaku.io) which produces a binary `ByteBuffer` containing the encoded data of my instance.

As suggested, I tried to convert the `ByteBuffer` to an `ArrayBuffer` and casting it to `BodyInit`. However, when running this code on Firefox 53.0.3, I do not receive a runtime error, but instead the payload contains just `[object ArrayBuffer]` and not the binary data itself.

Here's the code:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray.TypedArrayBufferOps._
import boopickle.Default._
import org.scalajs.dom.experimental.BodyInit
import org.scalajs.dom.experimental.beacon._   

case class Message(firstName: String, lastName: String)
val message = Message("John", "Doe")
val data = Pickle.intoBytes(message).arrayBuffer()
dom.window.navigator.sendBeacon("/api", data.asInstanceOf[BodyInit])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr do this instead:

```
val data = Pickle.intoBytes(message).typedArray()
dom.window.navigator.sendBeacon("/api", data.asInstanceOf[BodyInit])
```

You should use `typedArray()` and not `arrayBuffer()` because `ArrayBuffer` is a more lower-level construct that is not accepted by [`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) in Mozilla (it accepts an [`ArrayBufferView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView)).

Also note that `arrayBuffer()` by itself on a `ByteBuffer` is in general meaningless, since the `ByteBuffer` might only represent a part of the underlying buffer. You'd need to use `arrayBufferOffset()` as well.

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me. Bounty is yours in 2 h.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala.js, direct ByteBuffers are backed by TypedArrays.

Therefore, when you allocate your ByteBuffer, make sure it is direct:

```
val buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024)
```

Then, you can use [TypedArrayBufferOps](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/latest/#scala.scalajs.js.typedarray.TypedArrayBufferOps) to gain access to the underlying `TypedArray`:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray.TypedArrayBufferOps._
sendBeacon("http://foo.bar/", buf.typedArray)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. `[error]  found   : scala.scalajs.js.typedarray.Int8Array
[error]  required: org.scalajs.dom.experimental.BodyInit
[error]     (which expands to)  scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.|[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Blob,org.scalajs.dom.crypto.BufferSource],org.scalajs.dom.raw.FormData],String]`. Since I am using boopickle, I also tried the following: `Pickle.intoBytes(message).arrayBuffer().asInstanceOf[BufferSource]`, this compiles but the payload which will be sent is simply `[object ArrayBuffer]` which is obviously wrong.

Comment: I see. In this case I need more information to help you. Please update your question with a sample piece of code. In the current state I cannot help you, because I do not know what exact APIs you are talking about.

Comment: As far as I can understand, it is just the Scala.js DOM api being outdated. The fetch spec clearly states that `ArrayBuffer` is an acceptable datatype. Have you tried casting it to `BodyInit`?

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately the same as result as with the cast to `BufferSource` (see edit).